# loan payment calculator, how to implement multiple methods. Trouble developing method to interact with main method

Tags: java, methods

The idea of this assignment is to have multiple methods interact with each other.  I am asking the user for loan amount, interest rate and duration of loan.  Then the program is supposed to have one method that calculates the monthly rate, one method that calculates and returns the monthly payment and a method to print the loan statement (amt borrowed,annual interest rate, number of months, and the monthly payment).

I am not receiving any errors in the editor but my program just asks for the three inputs from the user and does not print the loan statement.  Any suggestions?

```
public class CarLoan {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare variables for main method
    double loanAmount;//double value loan amount 
    double annualInterestRate;//double value interest rate
    int numberOfMonths;//int value for number of months
    double monthlyPayment;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your loan.");
    loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate as a decimal. Ex. 7.5% = .075");
    annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of months you have to pay back your loan.");
    numberOfMonths = keyboard.nextInt();

}

public static double calcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate){
    double monthlyInterestRate;
        monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12);
        return monthlyInterestRate;
}//end method CalcMonthlyInterestRate

    public static double calcMonthlyPayment(double monthlyInterestRate, double loanAmount, int            numberOfMonths     ){
    double monthlyPayment;
    double calcMonthlyPayment;
        calcMonthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate*loanAmount)/(1-(1+monthlyInterestRate)-numberOfMonths);
        return monthlyPayment = calcMonthlyPayment;
}//end method CalcMonthlyPayment

public static void loanStatment (double loanAmount, double annualInterestRate, intnumberOfMonths,  double monthlyPayment){
 System.out.println("Your loan amount is " +loanAmount);
 System.out.println(annualInterestRate);
 System.out.println(numberOfMonths);
 System.out.println(monthlyPayment);
  }

 }//end main method


}//end main method
```

I am not sure if some of my code is still redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Since the main method is static and your CalcMonthlyInterestRate references your main method the CalcMonthlyInterestRate must also be static so that the two create a `static reference` to each other.

At the bottom of your post we see:

```
}//end main
}//end class
```

Class Methods referenced by the main method must also be inside its same class as well as being `static`. Once you start building your own classes and objects this won't always be the case

```
 }//end main  
       public static double CalcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
          double monthlyInterestRate;
          monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12);
          return monthlyInterestRate;
       }
 }//end class
```

To capture a double using your method just call something like this in your main method:

```
double answer = CalcMonthlyInterestRate(/*some double variable here*/); //in main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `CalcMonthlyInterestRate` need to be within your `CarLoan` class and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have it like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//instance of scanner class for input from user

public class CarLoan {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare variables for main method
        double loanAmount;//double value loan amount 
        double annualInterestRate;//double value interest rate
        int numberOfMonths;//int value for number of months

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your loan.");
        loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate as a decimal. Ex. 7.5% = .075");
        annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of months you have to pay back your loan.");
        numberOfMonths = keyboard.nextInt();

    }
}//end main method


public static double CalcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate)
{
    double monthlyInterestRate;
    monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12);
    return monthlyInterestRate;
}
```

There are a couple problems here... One is that *//end main method* is not really the end of the main method. It's the end of your *class*. All methods in Java have to be inside a class. Classes represent objects, and Java is "object-oriented". Each method on an object represents a "behavior" of that object. A behavior dangling applied to nothing is (most of the time) meaningless.

The "class, interface, or enum" expected means that where you are currently typing code, you can only put a class, an interface, or an enum. Those are the top level constructs of a Java program (unless you want to get technical with packages, etc...)

Putting the function inside the class (and fixing some code redundancy), we have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//instance of scanner class for input from user

public class CarLoan {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare variables for main method
        double loanAmount;//double value loan amount 
        double annualInterestRate;//double value interest rate
        int numberOfMonths;//int value for number of months

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of your loan.");
        loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate as a decimal. Ex. 7.5% = .075");
        annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double monthlyInterestRate = CalcMonthlyInterestRate(annualInterestRate);

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of months you have to pay back your loan.");
        numberOfMonths = keyboard.nextInt();
    } //end main method

    public static double CalcMonthlyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate)
    {
        return annualInterestRate / 12;
    } //end monthly interest method

} //end class
```

Also, methods in Java usually start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help.  I have a loose grasp of how classes are supposed to be set up and I understand that all of my methods are part of one class.  However, according to my text I should separate main methods from other methods inside a class.  And, this assignment is about methods interacting with each other.

Comment: I have edited the question.  Should i repost it as a new question?

Comment: Nah, we can just talk here. The reason I said it was redundant is because you can just `return annualInterestRate / 12`. Look at the way I implemented `calcMonthlyInterestRate`. You don't need a variable to return something. You can just return. Also, in your `calcMonthlyPayment` up above, just `return calcMonthlyPayment`. Really all you need to do is return that long calculation since your variable name doesn't give any more meaning to the code. There's no need for those extra local variables.

Comment: ok. but I call one of the variables in the final method.  Can i just call the method?  Also my statements will not print at the end..  Specifically, I want to print monthlyInterest rate.  Would i just say,                                                                           System.out.println (annualInterestRate/12);

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this, so perhaps you actually should post another question. I don't know what you mean by you "call one of the variables in the final method". And calling a method is fine... That println will print the monthly interest rate. You probably aren't printing anything because you're not calling any methods. Pass the three variables you read in as params to loanStatement and have that method call the other methods.